# UWP Frame Navigation class instances

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have an app that has three pages, therefore, in my main xaml "container" I have a frame that I use to show whichever of my three pages I want to show. So, when I switch out the page in the frame, I do this

```
 MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(page1));
```

My question is, if my user navigates to and from a bunch of times, the above will get called each time they navigate to page 1. Will this instantiate several instances of page1 (once for each time they navigate to it)?

I actually would like to have just one instance open during the lifecycle of the app and when navigation happens, just return the instance that was already created. In other words, have a method or class that does this (obviously this needs to be thought out more or cleaned up, just threw it together for this post)

```
 private page1 _page1;
 private Page ReturnPageForNavigation()
 {
      if(_page1 == null)
      {
           _page1 = new page1();
           return _page1;
      }
      return _page1;
 }
```

So, what is the best way to do navigation in my Frame? Should I just do typeof and return new each time? Should I implement something to track and return one instance?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set `NavigationCacheMode` property to `NavigationCacheMode.Required` in the page1 constructor.

Comment: Perfect! That seems easy. I will read about that setting too. I want to understand, will it then keep the class instantiated until the app closes?

Comment: Just the frame keep the instance, a new instance will be initialized if you use a new frame.